# Why Does MVC Not Bind when using Partial Views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial

Can someone tell me how I can get MVC to bind to a view model within a view model when using partial views?

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            AVm a = new AVm();
            BVm b = new BVm();
            a.BVm = b;

            return View(a);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(AVm vm)
        {
            string name = vm.BVm.Name; // will crash BVm == null


            return View(vm);
        }
    }
```

// Index View

```
@model MvcApplication4.Models.AVm

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Home",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <text>Id:</text> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Id)
    @Html.Partial("SharedView", Model.BVm)

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

// SharedView

```
@model MvcApplication4.Models.BVm

<text>Name:</text> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)



 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:


Line 26:         public ActionResult Index(AVm vm)
Line 27:         {
Line 28:             string name = vm.BVm.Name; // will crash BVm == null
Line 29: 
Line 30:
```

Comment: Can you fix your syntax first as your Action method has no method name. Also it seems that, that non named method is a get request so it would be all blank. You need to show all the related Action methods and your partial view code.

Comment: How come return type After the method name? As you are using Test1 model, to get 'Name' shouldn't you use vm.Test2.Name?

Comment: Ok updated. Should all make sense now.

Comment: Can I ask why this is a partial view? Just curious the reason. Why not use an EditorTemplate instead? Doing so will generate the inputs with the correct naming scheme (id = BVm_Name, name = BVm.Name) and your object will then bind properly and result in the data your are expecting.

Comment: Well this is first just an example. My real view is bigger and shared between views. I don't really like those Editor stuff. I find it when you use Edit/display helpers you losing putting html attributes on them. From my experience I always had to fight with them to get what I want.

Comment: @Khepri - If I do use the EditorTemplate how do I pass in the model? Does it have to AVm or could I pass in only BVm?

Comment: With an editor template you call it doing the standard @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BVm); We do this in several applications we have here. We'll have a Views/Store/AVm view and then in an EditorTemplates folder we'll create a template for BVm and it knows that it's part of a larger model. Not sure what you mean losing HTML attributes. It's just another view like any other.

Comment: By losing html attrbiutes I meant for  @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Id). Alot of people like to use Display and Editor but I always found that say if I wanted that field to be disabled or something like that.I can't just do @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Id, new {@disabled = "disabled"}). That's why I am sort of turned off from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your partial the model `BVm` doesn't know that its a property on a viewmodel `AVm`. So when you do something like `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)` it will just generate something like

```
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="" />
```

When what you really need is something like

```
<input type="text" name="BVm.Name" id="Name" value="" />
```

You could either generate the inputs yourself like suggested here, or you could try something like:

```
public ActionResult Index(AVm vm, BVm bvm)
```

Assuming there's no conflicting property names.

Comment: Did you mean to put a link somewhere or are you referring to someones else post? "...like suggested here". What is weird is I am pretty sure I did this in other projects and it worked. I will have to look into it. Kinda sucks this does not work.